# Load balancing on wordpress - 2 LAP web servers 1 Mysql DB - How?

Tags: mysql, linux, wordpress, apache, load-balancing

Here is the problem: my client wants to setup a load-balancing wordpress server to handle the increasing number of visitors.

2 Web servers will have setting below:

- Load balancer x 1
- Server #1: Linux, Apache, PHP 5, Wordpress 3.8.1
- Server #2: Linux, Apache, PHP 5, Wordpress 3.8.1
- Server #3: Linux, MySQL

Load balancer will direct traffic to web server #1, and #2, and #1 and #2 will connect to #3 MySQL to get information.

Notes:

- It is a must, so no need to consider another "Wordpress performance enhancement" solution.
- I understand that it will also has single point of failure, but it is fine.  My client just wants that.

My questions:

1. I will change the wp-config.php file to point to #3 database.  Is it ok?  Are there any potential problem?
2. I will also mount the /upload directory to share by two web servers, both writable.  Is it fine?
3. Session problem: how to share session between wordpress?  Somewhere on the web I read that the /tmp folder should be shared also, is it true?  If I want to save session to database, will it also work?
4. Apart from the questions above, did I miss other steps that are critical to success?  What should I pay attention to also?

Thanks in advance for your help.  All other result on the web are just using rackspace, AWS and other service, which is not what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my notes on how to setup my own Load Balancing servers without other cloud services.

[Wordpress Load balancing: 2 web servers 1 MySQL without any Cloud services](http://alucard-blog.blogspot.hk/2014/02/wordpress-load-balancing-2-web-servers.html)